# Using html/php form to upload files from mobile phone?

Tags: html, forms, mobile, upload

I have a form that need people to fill in and also an option to upload file/image if they needed to. I'm using `input type="file"` and works on desktop.

When comes to mobile, I can't seem to select any image from my phone and upload it straightaway. Is there an option that allow upload files using phone?

Comment: You can check if the device's browser supports the input='file' tag, and show it. Here is some context about it: http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/

Comment: @Kio Coan I'm using android KitKat and it does support `input type="file"`. However it only allows me to upload what I capture immediately using my camera, if I navigate through my gallery and select the image manually, it doesn't work.